# Is this a valid way to assign a random number to a variable?

Tags: java, random

I have seen a lot of different ways to generate random numbers in between a certain range.  Just today I came across the following piece of code. but upon doing research, I did not see anybody describe it this way.

```
Random ran = new Random();
int j = ran.nextInt(5+10);
```

My question is, does the code above assign a random integer to `j` between the numbers of 5 and 10?  If so, what if you wrote the second line of code like this `int j = rgen.nextInt(10+5);`

Comment: First, `ran != rgen`.

Comment: What kind of question is that @Daniel?  Of course it's a serious question.

Comment: I agree it's a bit naive... but I'm no sure it deserves a downvote.

Comment: @Tunaki, sorry, that was a typo.  It is fixed now.

Comment: I wonder why people keep saying this is not a worthy question.  I am a beginner and trying to learn the different methods of assigning a random int to a variable.

Comment: What happened when you ran your code a few times? What does the javadoc of `Random` say it does?

Comment: What do you think `5+10` does? Do you think it's different from `10+5`? Why do you think so? What do you think method arguments are?

Comment: I think it sets a range between max and min, but I did not see this way of doing it in my research.  Just wanted clarification on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate a random int within `[min, max[`:

```
Random r = new Random();
int number = r.nextInt(max - min) + min;
```

So in your case:

```
int j = r.nextInt(10 - 5) + 5;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  This helps clarify it.  Last question, why do you add the min value outside the bracket?